# SQL server Exception failed when converting the nvarchar value '2018-10-03' to data type int

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Getting error while executing SQL query in java
"SQL server Exception :com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2018-10-03' to data type int"

SQL query

```
String MemberId = “103113213”;
String StartDate = ”2019-05-20”;

    select distinct BLRC_CREATE_DTM,BLRC_AMT
    FROM CMC_BLRC_BILL_RCPT D,CMC_SBSB_SUBSC A,CMC_GRGR_GROUP C,CDS_INID_INVOICE B
WHERE A.GRGR_CK = C.GRGR_CK
AND A.SBSB_CK = B.SBSB_CK
AND B.BLEI_CK = D.BLEI_CK
AND A.SBSB_ID IN ('"+MemberId+"')
AND FORMAT(BLRC_CREATE_DTM, 'yyyy-MM-dd') ="+StartDate+"";
```

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed. (Unrelated, but still a great tip!)

Comment: SQL uses `DECLARE` to create a variable and doesn't have a `String` data type. This looks like an odd mix of C# and SQL. You should be parametrising your query too, not injecting the values.

Comment: Can you show us how you apply this query in your java code?

Comment: And why are you converting a date column to a string to compare to another date?

Answer (score 0):

```
String MemberId = “103113213”;
String StartDate = ”2019-05-20”;

    select distinct BLRC_CREATE_DTM,BLRC_AMT
    FROM CMC_BLRC_BILL_RCPT D,CMC_SBSB_SUBSC A,CMC_GRGR_GROUP C,CDS_INID_INVOICE B
WHERE A.GRGR_CK = C.GRGR_CK
AND A.SBSB_CK = B.SBSB_CK
AND B.BLEI_CK = D.BLEI_CK
AND A.SBSB_ID IN ('"+MemberId+"')
AND FORMAT(BLRC_CREATE_DTM, 'yyyy-MM-dd') = CONVERT(date, StartDate);
```

Please make sure you are provide input just date and saving date as well.